# window.open in quirks mode also changes subsequent page to quirks mode

Tags: javascript, vb.net, quirks-mode

I'm using window.open to open a new window from code behind to a page which runs in quirks mode. However, when I click this button to go to this second page, it changes the first page mode as well.

This is the piece of code that I wrote:

```
Dim url1 As String = "MYURL.html"
Response.Write("<script>")
Response.Write("newwindow=window.open('" + url1 + "','_blank');")
Response.Write("newwindow.focus()")
Response.Write("</script>")
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Note: my target page really should run in quirks mode, so this is not a part that I can ignore, and I have to do this with a button that runs at the server, so I cannot achieve the same effect with an anchor tag which has its target set to `_blank`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a way but this is a bit of a work around however it will do the job for now

```
Dim url1 As String = "MYURL.html"
Response.Write("<script>")
Response.Write("newwindow=window.open('" + url1 + "','_blank');")
Response.Write("newwindow.focus()")
Response.Write("window.open('" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "','_self')")
Response.Write("</script>")
```

the line below of the code would get the same url and open it in the same tab (like what `location.reload();` would do but I couldn't use it in this situation so I came up with this substitute) and as the first page has a meta tag to open the page in ie edge everything would seem fine.

```
Response.Write("window.open('" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "','_self')")
```

---

**Edit:**
if the pop-up blocker, blocks the site still the first page would go to quirk mode.. but with the code below it would alert the user to fix the problem and if the pop up blocker was disable it shows the second page

```
Dim url1 As String = "MYURL.html"    
Response.Write("<script>")
Response.Write("newwindow=window.open('" + url1 + "','_blank');")
Response.Write("if(!newwindow || newwindow.closed || typeof newwindow.closed=='undefined'){")
Response.Write("alert('please disable pop-up blocker for this site');")
Response.Write("}")
Response.Write("else{")
Response.Write("newwindow.focus();")
Response.Write("}")
Response.Write("window.open('" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "','_self')")
Response.Write("</script>")
```

---

**Edit 2**: I finally found out what was the problem...actually response.write was the reason that my first page go to the quirks mode and to fix it I used Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock like bellow to open my window and everything worked like it should

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("", "<script>window.open('" & MYURL & "', '_blank', 'toolbar=no');</script>")
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
Dim url1 As String = "MYURL.html"
Response.Write("<script>")
Response.Write("function fen_pop(url) {")
Response.Write("newwindow=window.open('" + url + "','_blank');")
Response.Write("if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus();}")
Response.Write("newwindow.focus();")
Response.Write("return false;")
Response.Write("}")
Response.Write("</script>")
```

in your html use a link :

```
<a href="#" onclick="return fen_pop('MYURL.html')">Link to popup</a>
```

the "return false;" added i think will fix your problem.
This is to prevent the browser from following the actual link.

---

another way to write this is :

```
Response.Write("<script>")
Response.Write("function fen_pop(url) {")
Response.Write("newwindow=window.open('" + url + "','_blank');")
Response.Write("if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus();}")
Response.Write("newwindow.focus();")
Response.Write("}")
Response.Write("</script>")
```

in html page :

```
<a href="#" onclick="fen_pop('MYURL.html'); return false;">Link to popup</a>
```

Comment: thanks for answering...I really should use this code on a button so I tried the above code on one however "return false" stops the new window from getting opened so the first page is only getting refreshed and goes to the quirks mode

Comment: nop, the function is called first this open the window. and after  return false block the source web page , retry it.

Comment: I tried it again but it still has the same effect I think this is happens because of it's run at server...I cannot add "fen_pop('MYURL.html'); return false;" directly in the onclick attribute of the button as it doesn't exist yet and if I write this return false without the fen_pop function in the code behind still it would have the same effect